# How can I invert part of a photo?

Tags: post-processing, negative

Is there an easy way to invert part of a photo in software? Is there a good image viewer that does that?

Comment: Welcome to Photo.Stackexchange! Could you provide a bit more detail to your question, such as what Operating System (Windows, a Linux, OS X, ...) you use, and any photo-editing software you have/use, as this will help us provide better answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, pretty much all image editing applications include *Invert* as a standard adjustment and will automatically apply it to the active selection (if there is one). Here are a couple of examples.

### Windows: [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)

Paint.NET is a great free image editor for Windows.

1. Make a selection
2. From the menu, pick **Adjustments** > **Invert Colors**

[image]

### Linux/Mac OS: [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

Much the same process:

1. Make a selection
2. From the menu, pick **Colours** > **Invert**

[image]

Comment: + for mentioning Paint.Net... It's really under appreciated.

Comment: Agreed, and it keeps getting better. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 5):

Most photo editing software (though generally not raw processors like Lightroom) has the ability to select parts of an image and to perform operations on that selection, and most software has the ability to make a photo negative.

If you want something freely available I suggest [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org). Photoshop and Photoshop Elements will also do it but they cost money.

Answer (score 0):

One program I like a lot is [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/). It's small and fast, and it will even run from a flash drive, without installing it on a PC. Among its many features is the ability to invert a selected areas. It's a free download.